# Change two variables with each other using functions and pointers

Tags: c, function, variables, pointers, double

I have to change the values of two variables with each other using the following function:

I made this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change_double(double *d1, double *d2);

int main()
{
    double *a, *b;
    printf("Write two variables of the type double.\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Normal variables: %d %d\n", a, b);
    change_double(&a, &b);
    printf("Changed variables: %d %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}

void change_double(double *d1, double *d2)
{
    double aux;
    aux=*d1;
    *d1=*d2;
    *d2=aux;
}
```

When I run this programm, I generally always get this result(example):

Normal variables: 321 123
Changed Variables: 82 321

Number 82 appears for some reason I don't know.
Thank you

Comment: You need to read the manual for `scanf` again.

Comment: `double a, b;` ... `scanf("%lf", &a);scanf("%lf", &b);`..`printf("Changed variables: %f %f\n", a, b);`

Comment: Besides @BLUEPIXY's comment, a and b should not be pointers.  Just make them double and pass their address, since the address of a non-pointer is a pointer, the function will get what it wants by just: `double a, b` ... `change_double(&a, &b);`  What you're really passing to the function with `double *a, *b` ...`change_double(&a, &b);` is `**a, **b`. You're not passing pointers to doubles when you do that, you're really passing *pointers* to *pointers* to doubles.  Which is not what you want and not what the function expects.

Comment: Nevermind, now it works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Changed Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap_double(double *d1, double *d2);

int main()
{
    double a, b;
    printf("Write two variables of the type double.\n");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    printf("Normal variables: %lf %lf\n", a, b);
    swap_double(&a, &b);
    printf("Changed variables: %lf %lf\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}

void swap_double(double *d1, double *d2)
{
    double aux;
    aux=*d1;
    *d1=*d2;
    *d2=aux;
}
```

Comment: Change `change_double` to `swap_doubles` for clarity ;-)

Comment: changed to swap_double ;-)